# Differential code coverage in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-pipelines

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops) says

> In order to get coverage metrics for a pull request, first configure a pipeline that validates pull requests. In this pipeline, configure the test tool you are using to collect code coverage metrics. Coverage results must then be published to the server for reporting.

I am not able to understand this. Any example or futher detailed information will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about create a pipeline to run a test and publish the test result (*collect and publish code coverage results*) to check how much the percentage of the changed code lines has been covered by your tests.

There's a [.Net Core example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#collect-code-coverage) mentioned in the doc you can refer to about how to test and publish the test result.

Notice: It's also mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops#prerequisites):

> the code coverage for pull requests feature discussed in this document is currently available only for .NET and .NET core projects using the Visual Studio code coverage results format (file extension .coverage).

Comment: Ok. However, I don't understand what this means "In order to get coverage metrics for a pull request, first configure a pipeline that validates pull requests."

Comment: And futhermore, how do I do this if I am using VSTest@2 task with codeCoverageEnabled as true for a ASP.NET pipeline (not core)

Comment: For the first question, i assume you might be confused about what is "a pipeline that validates pull requests.", please check [PR triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) and you will see this `Pull request validation` is only for GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud, you can configure a [branch policy for build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation).

Comment: For the second question, please check [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), and you will see "Other built-in tasks such as Visual Studio Test task and Dot NetCore CLI task automatically publish test results to the pipeline", the vstest task publish the test result automatically.

Comment: Is the pull request code coverage check feature available for python projects that run coverage tests using the `pytest-cov` package which generates the same file format as mentioned in your note `.coverage`?

Comment: @variable No, as explicitly stated in this answer.